# Swift 3 - Detect total number of touches on a screen at any time

Tags: swift3, uigesturerecognizer, multi-touch

I am trying to detect the number of fingers on a screen in a UIView, and then wait to show another view only if there are exactly 2 touches on the UIView.

So far, I have tried to detect the number of touches by using a UITapGestureRecognizer. It yields the right number of touches when called, but I cannot make it wait until there are two touches, as using a while statement on the `numberOfTouches` property freezes the app.

Comment: What do you mean "make it wait"? Why can't you just use a simple `if` to check if `numberOfTouches` equals 2 (when the gestureRecognizer fires) and only if the condition is true, show your view.

Comment: Is it possible to the code where you are handling the number of touches?